# How to get rid of undesirable params in response of a post request devise siginup custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, routes, http-post

**My Query**
I'm sending user hash as data. Why that user hash is also appended in the register attribute? How do I get rid of this or avoid this?

**my routes are**

```
devise_for :users, skip: :all
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      devise_scope :user do
        post "user/signup" => "users/registrations#create"
      end
    end
  end
```

**In routes**

`api_v1_user_signup POST   /api/v1/user/signup(.:format)                                                            api/v1/users/registrations#create {:format=>"json"}`

**post request I'm sending with params**

```
{
    "user" : {
        "email" : "example@exqample.com",
        "password" : "123456", 
        "imei" : "2345234523452345",
        "confirm_password" : "123456",
        "user_name" : "jhon"
    }
}
```

**Params I get**

`<ActionController::Parameters {"user"=>{"email"=>"example@exqample.com", "password"=>"123456", "imei"=>"2345234523452345", "confirm_password"=>"123456", "user_name"=>"jhon"}, "format"=>"json", "controller"=>"api/v1/users/registrations", "action"=>"create", "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"example@exqample.com", "password"=>"123456", "imei"=>"2345234523452345", "confirm_password"=>"123456", "user_name"=>"jhon"}}} permitted: false>`

Comment: **Question**: You want to use devise but manipulate routes, right?

Comment: @AmrAdel No. He wants to understand why is it when his request contains only `{user: {}}`, the params is showing with another key `registration` and sending the same params he is sending inside `user`. He wants a way to get rid of `registration`.

Answer (score 0):

That's the behaviour of Rails. If you only want `{user: ()}` then you need use this option in your controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  wrap_parameters :user, include: %i[email password imei confirm_password user_name]
end
```